# find out hexadecimal literal

Tags: html, hex

Anyone tell me what the hexadecimal literal for #419ddc or let me know how I can go about finding out?

Comment: I don't understand. Why isn't the hexadecimal literal simply `419ddc`? Do you mean **RGB** values?

Comment: You mean the HTML entity in hex form? `&#x419ddc;`

Comment: Like this 0xe4, 0xd0, 0xb1 - but obviously that not the right colour :)

Comment: 0x41, 0x9d, 0xdc. The syntax is #RRGGBB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hexadecimal literal `#419ddc` is the same as the RGB literal `rgb(65,157,220)` or `rgb(25%,62%,86%)`.

The format is #rrggbb, so red is 41 (= decimal 65), green is 9d (= decimal 157) and blue is dc (= decimal 220).